# How do you advertise your work if you cover multiple topics or niches?

Tags: short-story, marketing, genre, websites, social-media

Lets assume that you write articles which get published online (on your own website), but these cover a wide range of niches. Some very family friendly, some aimed at children, some horror based, and some erotic (maybe even beyond what you'd call NSFW).

What is the best way to advertise all of your work? I mean, you can't really set up a Twitter account and say "here's my latest article about a local boy and his dog", and then say, "Find out what Lisa did in her latest BDSM session".

Is there a platform / social network that can be used to showcase all of your work to multiple niches, without having to set up multiple profiles? For example, Pinterest allows one account with multiple boards, whereas Twitter would require multiple user accounts - Are there any similar to Pinterest with the ability to target different audiences?

Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/40583/running-multiple-multi-niche-blogs-as-an-individual/40589#40589 which appears to be the same user under a new account. My answer under that question is still my answer here. There doesn't appear to be any new information or practical difference in the 2 questions.

Comment: I edited this because I'm in the middle of doing tag edits, but I also VTC because it's a duplicate.  Wayne, just use your old account (or ask a moderator to help you merge them if you lost your password or something).  If you want to ask a followup question to the first, go for it.  (If the two Waynes are different people, then Wayne Six, just ask a different question.)

Comment: It's not strictly a duplicate @wetcircuit as this is more about showcasing work than communicating with potential clients. See my updated question for details.

Comment: Wayne, your edit has simply added a new reason to close rather than encouraging me to reopen. You've introduced a new question, which means the existing answers are responding to only half the question as it now reads. And what you've added is a [*shopping-for-a-product*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) question, which our Help Centre says is off-topic, primarily because of the limited longterm usefulness of such requests.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using a pseudonym for either the adult content ones or the children’s ones.

You are trying to establish a brand. People expect a certain consistency in an author’s works. You have two very different niches and it might be worthwhile to set up a separate site for one or the other.

Established authors who venture into a different genre will often select a pseudonym to avoid brand confusion and alienating their readership, who have come to expect them to write X.

Comment: Thanks. I've considered this approach, and it works to some extent, but my work is very random - I've used `short stories` as an example, but really this is more about article writing and photography projects - So while it's feasable to have a `Horror` and a `Fetish` pseudonym, there are countless possibilites considering I may write about nature, lifestyle, fashion and music, plus maybe local culture and sport. Where do you set a line for which pseudonym covers which niche/topic?

Answer (score 2):

As someone who also writes on a variety of topics, I can tell you unequivocally --it's a nightmare for "brand identity."  **Readers want to be able to come to you with consistent expectations.**

**DEFINITELY get one pseudonym/platform for your adult work, AND a different one for your family-oriented work.**  Those are two entirely separate niches with no expected overlap in audiences, and either one is complete poison to the other.

For all your other work, it's okay to use the same name and platform, but **don't expect to get much traction without specializing.**  Maybe you can establish a consistent lens through which you can present all the different things you're interested in.  For instance, my current blog is called "[Pop Culture Philosopher](http://popculturephilosopher.com)."  It covers a wide variety of topics, but it sets a baseline expectation for articles at the intersection of philosophy and popular culture.